# Dynamic Grid. How to?

Tags: java, android, gridview

I need to load buttons based on the database record.

For example, in my database, I have 4 records, then I want it to display like this:

```
----------------------------------
| Button 1 | Button 2 | Button 3 |
----------------------------------
|            Button 4            |
----------------------------------
```

Or for 5 records:

```
----------------------------------
| Button 1 | Button 2 | Button 3 |
----------------------------------
|    Button 4   |    Button 5    |
----------------------------------
```

Or for 6 records:

```
----------------------------------
| Button 1 | Button 2 | Button 3 |
----------------------------------
| Button 4 | Button 5 | Button 6 |
----------------------------------
```

I've tried to use GridView, but GridView doesn't do exactly what I need. For 4 buttons it becomes:

```
----------------------------------
| Button 1 | Button 2 | Button 3 |
----------------------------------
| Button 4 |
------------
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: maybe use a baglayout inside a gridlayout then you can have a grid with rows and each row is a baglayout

Comment: Use StaggeredGridLayoutManager instead of GridLayoutManager

Comment: @FarshidABZ, StaggeredGridLayoutManager doesn't seems to be able to do what I need to do. Any other idea? :)

Comment: @Lino, would you be able to point out the example of how to use it? I am having trouble to bind it from database. Any idea how? Thanks again :)

Comment: Hi All, thanks to Lino, I managed to use GridLayout. But I am having trouble bind it to the database. Any idea?

Comment: You need some logic which figures out how many rows are needed for your **n** amount of records. Then split up so you have at max 3 records per row. Then foreach row you have 3 scenarios: *1 record* put the button into the center of the bag layout. *2 records* put one of the buttons to the left, the other to the right side. *3 records* put one on the left, right and in the middle. This should work for ya ;)

Comment: Yep, I just did that. LOL... I am hoping to find an easy way (eg. GridView or RecyclerView) to do that automatically.